# In what property can I safely store a custom ID in a PDF Form Field?

Tags: pdf, pdf-form, aspose.pdf

In what property can I safely store a custom ID in a PDF Form Field?

https://apireference.aspose.com/net/pdf/aspose.pdf.forms/field

I was thinking maybe "AlternateName" but that is what adobe using for tool tips when hovering over the field. "MappingName" is another one I was thinking might work.

Seems crazy that adobe created this spec without giving each field it's own unique ID in the first place.

Comment: Field objects do have unique names. You can't have two different fields in the AcroForm dictionary using the same name. However, you can have widget annotations that represent the appearance of a field on the page. A field can have more than one widget associated with it but if there is only one widget per field, the dictionaries can be merged. For this reason, it can seem like fields don't have unique names since the field name of multiple widgets may resolve to the same field name. But they do, in fact, have unique names. What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can set your custom id as a string object with a custom key name in the field dictionary. I don't know if Aspose has an API for this low level approach.

Comment: Would you please elaborate your requirements a little more while sharing sample PDF document and some screenshots, via Google Drive, Dropbox, etc., so that we may investigate and assist you accordingly. Please also mention how can this be achieved with Adobe Acrobat? **PS:** I work with Aspose as support evangelist.

Comment: @FarhanRaza I basically would just like the add a new Form Field into a document and somehow save an ID (Guid) inside the field's metadata so that when I read the field later, I can retrieve that ID which will tie that field to data in a database/json file.

Comment: You can set the name of field as your custom ID to read the field later. It can simply replace default names like textbox1, textbox2 etc.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that but sometimes we have mutiple fields with the same names but with different coordinates.  I wanted an ID to identify which field and its coordinates maps to which data in the database/json file.

Comment: Alright. We would appreciate if you can share a sample document generated with Adobe Acrobat where you can utilize some property for same requirements, so that we may proceed to log a feature request accordingly.